# Python: Multi-Threaded Socket Master Server, with ability to call opened connections?

Tags: python, sockets, python-multithreading

I'm making in Python, Master Server Emulator for game, (don't tell me that Twisted for that is better - i know, i just doesn't have choise because game are using SSLv2 which is unsupported by Twisted)

Master Server creates new thread after enstabilishing connection.

What i'm trying to do:
To master server are connected both game server and client. After client decides to connect to the game server, master server should inform game server that client is trying to connect.

Master Server should inform game server, in the same connection (so please don't give me answers that requires opening new connection)

My first idea was to store information about connection, but basically don't know how to do that.

Is there any way to send data to enstabilished connection in other thread?

Comment: I'm completely confused about what's connected to what. Does the client connect to the master server first? Why? Why doesn't it just connect to the game server?

Comment: @James K Polk, game uses master server, to register, login accounts etc. Basically retrieving informations like server list.

Comment: ok, ok. So why does the master server need to tell the game server anything? Why can't the client simply pick a server from the server and make the connection?

Comment: @James K Polk, this is not my game, any questions to original game devs.
I logging packets via Wireshark, and master server are sending data to game server like client connection tokens etc seconds before client connects...

Comment: *using SSLv2 which is unsupported by Twisted* - I doubt that SSLv2 is not supported by Twisted only. It is probably not supported by the OpenSSL you are using (typical configurations don't have SSLv2 support compiled in) and that you will not fix the problem by moving to a different method of using the same OpenSSL library.